# How to include external python file i SQL request

Tags: python, mysql

I'm not experienced in Python.

I have the following Python code:

How can i import various values from files outside the file, and use them in a SQL request?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import MySQLdb
import Stamdata

from Stamdata import Varmekurve
K = Varmekurve
print K         #this vorks, and the value 1.5 from Varmekurve is printed.

#Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","Codename","MyDvoDb")

#prepare a cursor object using cursor  method
cursor = db.cursor()

            #Get SetTemp FROM SQL
sql = ("SELECT SetTemp FROM varmekurver WHERE kurvenummer = '1.5' AND TempSensor ='15'")
            #Here i would like to import the value from Varmekurve instead of '1.5', and the data from a DS18b20 temp. sensor instead of '15'.
            #The DS18B20 sensor are located in '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0316007914ff/w1_slave'


cursor.execute(sql)

results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
    print row[0]

db.close()
```

Only the Stamdata file are in the same library.

The Script shall control a motorvalve by calling the SetTemp and open/close a mix-valve if the temp. is to high or low (within 2-3 degrees)

But i haven't come that far yet :0)

Answer (score 0):

to dynamically change the value in the string from a variable do:

```
SELECT SetTemp FROM varmekurver WHERE kurvenummer = '{}' AND TempSensor ='{}'.format(val1, val2)
```

If you want to import these values from an external source, like a flat file, you can do it in a number of ways. For example using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).